# How to Delete a row of a table with using Psedo-Class in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a database with a table and that table with one column of varchar datatype.

Now I want to delete the rows without using

```
DELETE FROM songs_list WHERE songs_name = 'Shakira Waka Waka'
```

This is so because I cannot write the name of the checkbox with spaces. For example:

```
<?php for ($printedsno=1; $printedsno <$noio+1 ; $printedsno++){?>

<?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query7) ):?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo "cb".$row['songs_name'];?>"/>
<?php echo $printedsno?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $row['songs_name']?></br>
<?php
break;
endwhile;
}
?>
```

Here We can not write the checkbox name as `<?php echo "cb".$row['songs_name'];?>` 
That is why I want to use a psudo-Column. But For the Psudo-Column We can not be able to use a where clause beacause this column does'nt exist.

I want to delete the row from table with only column.

```
<?php
include 'database.php';

$noofsongs = "select * from songs_list";
$query8 = mysqli_query($con, $noofsongs);
$noio = mysqli_num_rows($query8);
$flag = 0;
$del = 0;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query8);
$song_names = $row['songs_name'];
if(isset($_POST['deletethis'])){
for($j=1; $j<=$noio ;$j++){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query8) ){
    if (isset($_POST['cb'.$song_names])){
    $deletesongsquery = "DELETE FROM `songs_list` WHERE `songs_name` = $song_names" ;
    $query4 = mysqli_query($con, $deletesongsquery);
    if($query4){ $del++;} 
    $flag = $flag + 1;

            }               
    }
    }
    if($del != $flag){echo "Can Not Be Deleted All Selected Songs.";}
    else{echo "Deleted $del Selected Songs.";}
 }
?>
```

Can anyone help me in this??

Comment: `$song_names` must be wrap around quotes better learn prepare statement

Comment: This is _one of the reasons_ why we ALWAYS add a `id` column that is `auto increment` So we have a simple number that uniquely identifies each row in the table

Comment: You  could also try looking at the `value` property of a checkbox